# AirPods 2nd Gen. with firmware 2A364 dropped volume level in non-iOS Devices

Tags: audio, hardware, sound-volume, firmware, airpods

When I bought new Airpods 2nd gen, the firmware it came with was 1A673. The volume level on my android phone (OnePlus 6T) when connected was quite loud and everything was good.

But when I connected my Airpods to my iPad with iOS 13.1 the firmware on these got updated to 2A364 and then when connected to my android phone, music volume started getting low. I tried with other android phones too.

But the thing is during the phone calls the volume comes out loud but low only on music or videos.

How do I fix this?

[image: airpod info]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I fix this issue in non-ios device? Is it possible to downgrade to old firmware version? @IconDaemon

Comment: There is no fix for this. Perhaps you might need to invest in other Bluetooth headphones, preferably one's with an app that you can use to control sound levels and audio quality.

Comment: As such the frequency of apple updating the firmware is quite long "https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/OTA_Updates/AirPods_(2nd_generation)" - Is there any way to reach out to apple showing this issue? And expect the update very soon.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and considering its an apple device, there isn't really any way to downgrade them. You're probably going to have to wait until apple fixes the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Since there’s no documented way to roll back firmware on these, you would presumably contact Apple and/or wait for a patch to put the volume back if this change was not intentional by Apple.